# Howto download file from ftp server using swift

Tags: ios, swift, ftp

Hello I try to download an XML file from ftp server but I have a problem with the CFRreadStreamRead function. Because I don't know what I should set as "_ buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer" parameter. I got this function from [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFReadStreamRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFReadStreamRead) On the code below you see how I currently try it. I hope you can help me.

```
 public func openFTPConnection()
{
    var url: CFStringRef
    url = "Test" as NSString
    var requestURL: CFURLRef
    requestURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, url, nil);

    let ftpStream = CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(kCFAllocatorDefault, requestURL).takeRetainedValue()
    var state = CFReadStreamOpen(ftpStream)

    if state == 0
    {
        println("Fehler beim verbinden")
    }
    else
    {
        println("Verbindung erfolgreich")
    }

    var numBytesRead = 0
    var bufSize = 4096
    var buf = [UInt8](count: bufSize, repeatedValue: 0)

    do
    {
        numBytesRead = CFReadStreamRead(ftpStream, buf, bufSize)
    }
    while( numBytesRead > 0 );


    CFReadStreamClose(ftpStream)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Type>` parameter, a`[Type]` array can be passed
as "inout value" via `&` (which is passed as a pointer to the start of the array):

```
numBytesRead = CFReadStreamRead(ftpStream, &buf, bufSize)
```

For more information, see [Interacting with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html) in the
"Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" documentation.